# Do the fixes for bugs 327 and 535 fix the devpoll issue as well along with Epoll?

Tags: netty, java, epoll

Here is the thread dump:

```
"New I/O client worker #23-1" prio=3 tid=0x007c1400 nid=0x28bc runnable [0xed17f000..0xed17f920]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at sun.nio.ch.DevPollArrayWrapper.poll0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.DevPollArrayWrapper.poll(DevPollArrayWrapper.java:164)
at sun.nio.ch.DevPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(DevPollSelectorImpl.java:68)
at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:69)
- locked <0xefd18e90> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$1)
- locked <0xefd18e80> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
- locked <0xefd012d8> (a sun.nio.ch.DevPollSelectorImpl)
at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:80)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:158)
at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.IoWorkerRunnable.run(IoWorkerRunnable.java:46)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

"device-factory-timer-114-thread-1" prio=3 tid=0x0092ac00 nid=0x28ba waiting on condition [0xedd7f000..0xedd7fc20]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
- parking to wait for  <0xefd01460> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:158)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1925)
at java.util.concurrent.DelayQueue.take(DelayQueue.java:160)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:583)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:576)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:947)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

This is quite similar to the epoll issue. Please let me know if the issue is already fixed or if you have any plans to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If you think there is an issue please open a bug-report with all the needed infos.

Comment: This issue is seen in Netty 3.1.5.
The latest version 3.5.X uses DeadLockProofWorker which internally call the Epoll. The 3.1.5 version uses IoWorkerRunnable which might be calling the Devpoll.
Can anybody tell if netty3.5.7 works with the code developed on 3.1.5? Are there any API changes between these versions? can I use the old code with the new Netty 3.5.7 without any changes?

Comment: There are a few changes but they are more likely not affect most users. I would definitely try to upgrade and see if it is fixes. 3.1.5 is really old